# How to create a Hierarchy, using Angular 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular7, angular8, angular9

I want to create a hierarchy from a json file using **Angular 2 or Angular 4**. Hierarchy of location may change based on the requirement. Can anyone suggest me how to create a required template. Possible cases are mentioned below.

file name : location.json

```
{
  "name" : "India",
  "children" : 
      {
         "name" : "Karnataka",
         "children" : 
             {
                "name" : "Banglore",
                "children" : 
                   [
                     {"val" : "silk"},
                     {"val" : "agara"}
                   ]                                         
             }
       }
},
 {
  "name" : "India",
  "children" : 
       {
         "name" : "goa",
         "children" : 
             [
                {"val" : "panji"},
                {"val" : "abc"}
             ]                                         
      }
}
```

CASE 1

```
<div> India
  <div> Karnataka
    <div> Banglore
      <div> silk </div>
      <div> agara </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
<div> India 
  <div> goa
    <div> panji</div>
    <div> abc</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Note that your desired result is invalid HTML. `<ul>` elements cannot have text nodes as direct descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sharing a working code for designing hierarchy.

> **Note** : **node-sass** is required to compile hierarchy.component.scss
>
> to install node-sass :  **npm install node-sass**

---

**hierarchy.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, SimpleChange, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Node } from './hierarchy.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hierarchy',
  templateUrl: './hierarchy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hierarchy.component.scss']
})
export class HierarchyComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() data: Array<Node>;
  @Input() selectedNodeIds: Array<string> = [];
  @Output() selectedIds: EventEmitter<Array<string>> = new EventEmitter<Array<string>>();

  public hierarchyData: Array<Node>;
  public showHiearchy: boolean;
  private actingNode: string;


  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Hierarchy';
    this.showHiearchy = false;
    this.hierarchyData = new Array<Node>();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  // go to parent and set full or partial select. Their method.
  private setParentFullOrPartialSelected(isChecked: boolean, node: Node, parent: Node) {
    if (isChecked) {
      if (parent) {
        if (this.checkAllChildOfNodeSelected(parent)) {
          parent.allSelected = true;
          this.setParentFullOrPartialSelected(isChecked, parent, parent.parentRef);
        } else {
          this.removeAllSelected(parent);
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.removeAllSelected(node);
      this.setParentPartialSelected(node);
    }
  }

  private checkAllChildOfNodeSelected(parentNode: Node): boolean {
    const nodes: Array<Node> = parentNode.children;
    let condition = true;
    (Array.isArray(nodes)) ? condition = nodes.every((node: Node) => this.isAllSelected(node)) : null;
    return condition;
  }

  public isAllSelected(node: Node): boolean {
    const condition = node.allSelected ? node.allSelected : true;
    return condition && (node.allSelected);
  }

  private removeAllSelected(node: Node) {
    node.allSelected ? node.allSelected = false : null;
  }

  private setParentPartialSelected(node: Node) {
    if (node.parentRef) {
      node.parentRef.allSelected ? node.parentRef.allSelected = false : null;
      this.setParentPartialSelected(node.parentRef);
    }
  }


  // Update parents and their method
  private updateParents(isChecked: boolean, node: Node) {
    const parent = node ? node.parentRef : null;
    if (parent) {
      if (isChecked) {
        parent.checked = isChecked;
        this.updateParents(isChecked, parent);
      } else {
        if (!this.isSomeChildOfNodeSelected(parent)) {
          parent.checked = isChecked;
          if (this.isSelected(parent)) {
            this.removeSelectedNodeId(parent);
          }
          this.updateParents(isChecked, parent);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private isSomeChildOfNodeSelected(parentNode: Node): boolean {
    const nodes: Array<Node> = parentNode.children;
    let condition = false;
    (Array.isArray(nodes)) ? condition = nodes.some((node: Node) => node.checked) : null;
    return condition;
  }

  public checkboxChanged(isChecked: boolean, node: Node, parent: Node = null) {
    node.checked = isChecked;
    node.parentRef = parent;
    this.actingNode = node.id;
    node.allSelected = isChecked;
    // go to parent and set full or partial select.
    this.setParentFullOrPartialSelected(isChecked, node, parent);
    // go to parent and make them checked or unchecked.
    this.updateParents(isChecked, node);
    // go to child and select them or de-select.
    this.updateChildrens(isChecked, node);
    this.updateSelectedNodeIds(isChecked, node);
    this.selectedIds.emit(this.selectedNodeIds);
  }


  private updateChildrens(isChecked: boolean, node: Node) {
    const childNodes: Array<Node> = node.children;
    if (childNodes) {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
      for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
          childNodes[i].checked = isChecked;
          childNodes[i].allSelected = isChecked;
          if (isChecked) {
            this.updateSelectedNodeIds(isChecked, childNodes[i]);
          } else {
            this.removeSelectedNodeId(childNodes[i]);
          }
          this.updateChildrens(isChecked, childNodes[i]);   // use recursion to update childrens within children.
      }
    }
  }

  private updateSelectedNodeIds(isChecked: boolean, node: Node) {
    if (isChecked) {
      if (!this.isSelected(node)) {
        this.selectedNodeIds.push(node.id);
      }
    } else {
      this.removeSelectedNodeId(node);
    }
  }

  private removeSelectedNodeId(node: Node) {
    if (this.isSelected(node)) {
      const index = this.selectedNodeIds.indexOf(node.id);
      this.selectedNodeIds.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  public isPartiallySelected(node: Node) {
      return node.checked && !node.allSelected;
  }

  public isSelected(node: Node): boolean {
    if (this.selectedNodeIds) {
      return this.selectedNodeIds.indexOf(node.id) > -1;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public toggleHierarchy() {
    this.showHiearchy = !this.showHiearchy;
  }

  public expandNode(node: Node) {
    node.expanded = !node.expanded;
  }

  /**
   *  For each node it will set referance to parent node and also ensure to initilize the variables.
   * @param nodes List of node.
   * @param parentNode parent of node.
   */
  public setNodeDefault(nodes: Array<Node>, parentNode: Node = null) {
    nodes.forEach( (node: Node) => {
      node.allSelected = false;
      node.checked = false;
      node.expanded = true;
      node.parentRef = parentNode;
      if (node.children) {
        this.setNodeDefault(node.children, node);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const dataChange: SimpleChange = changes['data'];

    if (dataChange && dataChange.currentValue) {
      this.hierarchyData = new Array<Node>( new Node('all', 'Select All', this.data));
      // If select all is not required, then comment above line and use below line code
      //  this.hierarchyData = this.data;
      this.setNodeDefault(this.hierarchyData);
    }
  }

}
```

---

**hierarchy.component.html**

```
<div class="flex-inline-col dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown__btn" (click)=toggleHierarchy()>{{name}}</div>
    <div class="dropdown__content" [class.toggle-drop-down]="showHiearchy">
        <div class="dropdown__search">
            <input type="text" class="dropdown__search" autofocus>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown__hierarchy">
            <li class="dropdown__hierarchy__list">
                <ul class="hierarchy">
                    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="hierarchyNode; context: {$implicit: hierarchyData, level: 'first'}"></ng-container>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #hierarchyNode let-hierarchyData let-level="level" let-parent="parent">
    <li *ngFor="let node of hierarchyData" [class.last-children]="!node.children"
        class="flex-col hierarchy__item">
        <div>
            <div *ngIf="node.children" class="flex-inline hierarchy__item__icon" (click)="expandNode(node)">
                <svg *ngIf="!node.expanded" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                    <title>circle-right</title>
                    <path d="M16 0c-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16s7.163 16 16 16 16-7.163 16-16-7.163-16-16-16zM16 29c-7.18 0-13-5.82-13-13s5.82-13 13-13 13 5.82 13 13-5.82 13-13 13z"></path>
                    <path d="M11.086 22.086l2.829 2.829 8.914-8.914-8.914-8.914-2.828 2.828 6.086 6.086z"></path>
                </svg>
                <svg *ngIf="node.expanded"  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                    <title>circle-down</title>
                    <path d="M32 16c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16s-16 7.163-16 16 7.163 16 16 16 16-7.163 16-16zM3 16c0-7.18 5.82-13 13-13s13 5.82 13 13-5.82 13-13 13-13-5.82-13-13z"></path>
                    <path d="M9.914 11.086l-2.829 2.829 8.914 8.914 8.914-8.914-2.828-2.828-6.086 6.086z"></path>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check_{{node.id}}"
                class="flex-inline hierarchy__item__checkbox"
                [checked]="node.checked || isSelected(node)"
                (change)="checkboxChanged($event.target.checked, node, parent)">
            <label for="check_{{node.id}}" class="flex-inline hierarchy__item__label">
                <span class="hierarchy__item__icon hierarchy__item__circle" *ngIf="!node.checked">
                    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                        <title>radio-unchecked</title>
                        <path d="M16 0c-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16s7.163 16 16 16 16-7.163 16-16-7.163-16-16-16zM16 28c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12s5.373-12 12-12c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12s-5.373 12-12 12z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <span class="hierarchy__item__icon hierarchy__item__circle-checked" *ngIf="node.checked && node.allSelected">
                    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                        <title>checkmark</title>
                        <path d="M21.82 13.030l-1.002-1.002c-0.185-0.185-0.484-0.185-0.668 0l-6.014 6.013-2.859-2.882c-0.186-0.185-0.484-0.185-0.67 0l-1.002 1.003c-0.185 0.185-0.185 0.484 0 0.668l4.193 4.223c0.185 0.184 0.484 0.184 0.668 0l7.354-7.354c0.186-0.185 0.186-0.484 0-0.669zM16 3c-7.18 0-13 5.82-13 13s5.82 13 13 13 13-5.82 13-13-5.82-13-13-13zM16 26c-5.522 0-10-4.478-10-10 0-5.523 4.478-10 10-10 5.523 0 10 4.477 10 10 0 5.522-4.477 10-10 10z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <span class="hierarchy__item__icon hierarchy__item__circle-minus" *ngIf="node.checked && !node.allSelected">
                    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="28" viewBox="0 0 24 28">
                        <title>minus-circle</title>
                        <path d="M19 15v-2c0-0.547-0.453-1-1-1h-12c-0.547 0-1 0.453-1 1v2c0 0.547 0.453 1 1 1h12c0.547 0 1-0.453 1-1zM24 14c0 6.625-5.375 12-12 12s-12-5.375-12-12 5.375-12 12-12 12 5.375 12 12z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                {{node.name}}
            </label>
                
        </div>
        <ul *ngIf="node.children" class="hierarchy" [style.display]="!node.expanded ? 'none' : 'block'">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="hierarchyNode; context: {$implicit: node.children, level: 'second', parent: node}"></ng-container>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ng-template>
```

---

**hierarchy.component.scss**

```
* {
    &,
    &:before,
    &:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
}
.flex {  
    display: flex;
}

.flex-col {  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-inline {  
    display: inline-flex;
}

.flex-inline-col {  
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.absCenter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}



.dropdown {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;

    &__btn {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        height: 35px;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: UPPERCASE;
        cursor: pointer;

        &:after {
            content: "";
            width: 0; height: 0; position: absolute; right: 5px; top:45%;
            border-top: 5px solid #000;
            border-left: 5px solid transparent;
            border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        }

        &:active {
            transform: translateY(2px);
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
        }
    }

    &__content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 38px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 99;
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    &__search {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    }

    &__hierarchy {
        list-style: none;
        max-height: 270px;
        overflow: auto;

        &__list {
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
    }
}

.toggle-drop-down {
    display: block;
}

svg {
    width: 20px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
}

.hierarchy {
    margin-left: 10px;

    &__item {
        padding: 5px 0px;

        &__icon {
            width: 20px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        &__label {
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        &__checkbox {
            align-self: center;
            display: none;
        }
    }
}

.last-children {
    margin-left: 35px;
}
```

---

**hierarchy.model.ts**

mockData is for testing purpose. Once application is functional, remove this mockData.

```
export class Node {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public name: string,
        public children?: Array<Node>,
        public allSelected?: boolean,
        public expanded?: boolean,
        public checked?: boolean,
        public parentRef?: Node,
    ) { }
}

export const mockData: Array<Node> = new Array<Node>(
    new Node('1000', 'First level 1', [
        new Node('1100', 'Second level 11', [
            new Node('1110', 'Third level 111', [
                new Node('1111', 'Fourth level 1111'),
                new Node('1112', 'Fourth level 1112'),
                new Node('1113', 'Fourth level 1113'),
                new Node('1114', 'Fourth level 1114')
            ]),
            new Node('1120', 'Third level 112', [
                new Node('1121', 'Fourth level 1121'),
                new Node('1122', 'Fourth level 1122'),
                new Node('1123', 'Fourth level 1123'),
                new Node('1124', 'Fourth level 1124')
            ])
        ]),
        new Node('1200', 'Second level 12', [
            new Node('1210', 'Third level 121', [
                new Node('1211', 'Fourth level 1211'),
                new Node('1212', 'Fourth level 1212'),
                new Node('1213', 'Fourth level 1213'),
                new Node('1214', 'Fourth level 1214')
            ]),
            new Node('1220', 'Third level 122', [
                new Node('1221', 'Fourth level 1221'),
                new Node('1222', 'Fourth level 1222'),
                new Node('1223', 'Fourth level 1223'),
                new Node('1224', 'Fourth level 1224')
            ])
        ])
    ]),
    new Node('2000', 'First level 2', [
        new Node('2100', 'Second level 21', [
            new Node('2110', 'Third level 211', [
                new Node('2111', 'Fourth level 2111'),
                new Node('2112', 'Fourth level 2112'),
                new Node('2113', 'Fourth level 2113'),
                new Node('2114', 'Fourth level 2114')
            ]),
            new Node('2120', 'Third level 212', [
                new Node('2121', 'Fourth level 2121'),
                new Node('2122', 'Fourth level 2122'),
                new Node('2123', 'Fourth level 2123'),
                new Node('2124', 'Fourth level 2124')
            ])
        ]),
        new Node('2200', 'Second level 22', [
            new Node('2210', 'Third level 221', [
                new Node('2211', 'Fourth level 2211'),
                new Node('2212', 'Fourth level 2212'),
                new Node('2213', 'Fourth level 2213'),
                new Node('2214', 'Fourth level 2214')
            ]),
            new Node('2220', 'Third level 222', [
                new Node('2221', 'Fourth level 2221'),
                new Node('2222', 'Fourth level 2222'),
                new Node('2223', 'Fourth level 2223'),
                new Node('2224', 'Fourth level 2224')
            ])
        ])
    ])
);
```

---

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Node, mockData } from './hierarchy/hierarchy.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public hierarchyData: Array<Node>;
  public selectedNodeIds: Array<string> = [];
  public selectedIds: Array<string> = [];


  constructor() {
    this.hierarchyData = mockData;
  }

  public changedSelectedIds(ids: Array<string>) {
    this.selectedIds = ids;
  }
}
```

---

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <app-hierarchy name="Hierarchy" 
        [data]="hierarchyData" 
        [selectedNodeIds]="selectedNodeIds"
        (selectedIds)="changedSelectedIds($event)">
    </app-hierarchy>
</div>
```

**Output**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first case should be relatively easy, as it matches your data structure. I'd first add a variable to your .ts file that holds the data return. Something like `countryData`. You'd want to add something like the following to your template.

```
<ul class="country">
  <li>{{countryData.name}}</li>
  <ul class="state">
    <li>{{countryData.children.name}}</li>
      <ul class="city">
        <li>{{countryData.children.children.name}}</li>
          <ul class="items">
            <li *ngFor="let item of countryData.children.children.loc">{{item.val}}</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

I added list items under the top level unordered lists to make sure the output was valid HTML. The template is a bit messy when traversing the object each time you need it, so in your .ts you could set other variables for the lower items.

```
let countryData = [JSON call response or data here];
let stateData = countryData.children;
let cityData = countryData.children.children;
let itemData = countryData.children.children.loc;
```

Then your template would look like this.

```
<ul class="country">
  <li>{{countryData.name}}</li>
  <ul class="state">
    <li>{{stateData.name}}</li>
      <ul class="city">
        <li>{{cityData.name}}</li>
          <ul class="items">
            <li *ngFor="let item of itemData">{{item.val}}</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

For Case 2, you'd just need to leave off the city level unordered list and leave in the item level. For Case 3, you'd need to have an array at the city level, so you'd need to add something like `*ngFor="let city of cityData` on the city level list item and adjust the city and item template variables to reference `{{city.name}}` and `let item of city.loc` so that it all inherits correctly as you loop through.

Comment: what if in **first** json data **state** object is missing i.e. **Karnata** and in **second** json data, one more hierarchy of object with property **name** and **children** is available. so how to create unordered list at run-time, after fetching data from the source. @tim-mcelwee, i believe you got my point.

Comment: In my case, Json data varies from client to client. There could be a situation, where 2-3 level of hierarchy object may also be added, and in some case there could be no **children** and only **loc** property is there

Comment: Is there any consistency to your data? Such as, you'll always have country and state?

Comment: sorry for replying you very late, there is no consistency in data. Level may have   world => Continent => Region => country => state => city => town => site.    or it may have   world => site.

Comment: I have come up with solution, working on improving it, once it is done, then i will post the code

Comment: @PrayagSharma were you able to make them dynamic...can you let us know the code/approach for the same

Comment: @shikhar yes, i will post this weekend.